# How to make a POST request instead of GET when Ok is clicked in Confirmation Popup (Node, Express, Jade)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have a web page rendering tables with rows and columns using Jade template. I need to make a POST request when i click "Ok" in confirmation box for delete.

Now am able to create a Delete Confirmation popup with "Cancel" and "Ok" buttons.

"Cancel" closes the confirmation box as expected. But choosing "Ok" navigates and shows information(Actually a GET request). Instead of GET request, whenever "Ok" is clicked, it should make a POST request.

How can i make it a POST request?

Screenshots,
[image: Table data]
[image: Confirmation popup]

Code for Delete button,

```
a.btn.btn-default(href='/removepage/'+value.PLANT+'/'+value.MATERIAL+'/'+value.CUSTOMER+'/'+value.RATE+'/'+value.CURRENCY+'/'+value.PRICE_UNIT+'/'+value.COND_UNIT+'/'+value.PORTAL_USER, onClick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?')") Delete
```

Code for GET request,

```
router.get('/removepage/:PLANT/:MATERIAL/:CUSTOMER/:RATE/:CURRENCY/:PRICE_UNIT/:COND_UNIT/:PORTAL_USER', (req, res) => {
  console.log("Render check");
  // console.log(req.params)
  res.render('removepage', 
  { title: 'Delete Page - Are you sure to delete?', plant: req.params.PLANT, material: req.params.MATERIAL, 
  currency: req.params.CURRENCY, rate: req.params.RATE, price_unit: req.params.PRICE_UNIT, 
  cond_unit: req.params.COND_UNIT, customer: req.params.CUSTOMER, portal_user: req.params.PORTAL_USER});
});
```

Code for POST request,

```
router.post('/removepage', (req, res) => {
  console.log("Hello", req.body);
  client.connect(() => {
    console.log('Connecting');
    client.invoke("ZSD_CP_PRICE_DELETE", 
    {P_PLANT: req.body.P_PLANT, 
    P_MATERIAL: req.body.P_MATERIAL, 
    P_CUSTOMER: req.body.P_CUSTOMER
    },
    (err, result) => {
      console.log('Invoking')
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return err;
      }
      console.log(result);
    });
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});
```

[image: Get and Post Request in same js file]

Comment: you use "a" tag for "ok" button, a tags are allways send "get" request

Comment: you can use javascript  to send "POST" request, or ("DELETE" which seems better for your case )

Comment: @happyZZR1400 I need to make "post" request

Comment: you need to place <script> tag at bottom of you page with 
definition of "handlerOK" function. (or you can use external javascript file and then refence it using "src" of script - <script src="pathToJSFile"></script>)

Answer (score 1):

Here is javascript for send POST request

```
fetch('/removepage', {
  method: 'POST'
}, {
 P_PLANT: value.P_PLANT, 
 P_MATERIAL: value.P_MATERIAL, 
 P_CUSTOMER: value.P_CUSTOMER        
})
```

You need to attach this to your "ok" button click

```
 a.btn.btn-default onClick="handlerOK(value.PLANT, value.MATERIAL, value.CUSTOMER)") Delete
```

Define handlerOk function at external file "script.js" and add reference to jade like this:script(src="/script.js")

```
function handlerOK(PLANT, MATERIAL, CUSTOMER) {
  const confirmed = confirm('are you sure you want to delete?');
  if (!confirmed) return;
  fetch('/removepage', {
    method: 'POST'
   }, {
   P_PLANT: PLANT, 
   P_MATERIAL: MATERIAL, 
   P_CUSTOMER: CUSTOMER        
  })
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question with new screenshot where you can see i have Get and Post request in single **.js** file. I don't know how to make it Post request when Ok is clicked :-(

Comment: Tried - onClick="handlerOK(value.PLANT, value.MATERIAL, value.CUSTOMER)" For value.MATERIAL, in console it shows **ReferenceError: MANGO is not defined localhost:8000:1:1 onclick http://localhost:8000/:1** For value.CUSTOMER, the actual value is **0000100001** but in console it shows **32769** It didn't work as expected

Comment: can you open "newtwork" panel at chrome dev tools (f12 key)  and see if "POST" request is sent when "ok" button clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You could send a [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) :

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", '/removepage', true);

var body = ""; // Anything you want to send


xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
        //treating the result here
    }
}
xhr.send(body);
```